# Using CSS or jQ, how can I show this section element on :hover?

Tags: css, animation

Okay, I know this basic question has been asked (and I've done this before) but this is different.

http://matiny.tk/warframe/mission.html

Okay, you see all that stuff moving? It is in the `<section>` of this...

```
<div id="main">
            <a href="1/cover.html"><img src="images/ch1.jpg" alt="" id="ch1" /></a>
            <a href="tango/1.html"><img src="images/tango.jpg" alt="" id="tango"/></a>
            <section>
               <img src="images/pngs/loka.png" alt="" id="loka" />
               <img src="images/pngs/blood.png" alt="" id="blood" />
               <img src="images/pngs/smoke.png" alt="" id="smoke" />
               <img src="images/pngs/stalk.png" alt="" id="stalk" />
            </section>
```

With the following style...

```
#loka, #blood, #smoke, #stalk {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;   
}
```

And with some animations, you know how that goes.

I want when a person hovers over the "Chapter 1" image (the 1st `<a>`) for the `<section>` to appear only then, and stay invisible otherwise. It looks like the pngs in the `<section>` are overlaid on top of everything.

Ok, so I use z-index: -1. The images disappear.
I make the Chapter 1 thumbnail absolute and I try then, and I still fail. Can you help me out?

Comment: Tried jQuery's mouseover and mouseleave events, combined with .hide() and .show() functions?

Comment: Well in this case, the issue was made more complex by z-indexing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go.](https://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ucrvs5ko/1/)

```
a {
    padding:5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
section {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1200ms;
}
a:first-child:hover ~ section {opacity: 1;}
```

Important parts: make sure the z-index of the links is higher than that of section.

---

However, I took the time and liberty to improve your code drastically. Especially with an eye on expansion of your page and SEO.

[Here it is.](https://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ucrvs5ko/3/)

1. Improved SEO: using a list with proper text values and links
2. For screenreader: links with proper text
3. Prettier fade in and animation (in my opinion. This is *very* subjective and you should adjust to what you like!)
4. Better structured CSS (I used SCSS in the fiddle though)

Comment: I notice that your animation actually stops on mouseout. How'd you accomplish that?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. You based the animation on :hover.  Very clever.

Comment: @Matiny I did that to be sure that the elements weren't moving when they weren't visible. If they are moving when they are not visible that would be inefficient and spend resources (cpu power) that could be used for something else. Especially on mobile devices this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

very specific css answer based on your html structure:

```
section {display:none;}

#main a:first-child:hover ~ section {
display:block;
}
```

[heres a fiddle demonstrating it.  (i didnt bother to give your images a proper src)](https://jsfiddle.net/ucrvs5ko/)

the `~` is the [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), which doesnt get enough love :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:none` to your section like

```
section {
 display: none;
}
```

And I see that when you hover over the first a, you add a class `chapter1` to the body, that is good. Just add this to your css:

```
.chapter1 section {
 display: block !important;
}
```

And it should work.